# How should I resolve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null Exception?

Tags: java, exception, ssl, stream

I am working on a SSL client server program and I have to reuse the following method.

```
private boolean postMessage(String message){
    try{ 
         String serverURLS = getRecipientURL(message);

         serverURLS = "https:\\\\abc.my.domain.com:55555\\update";

         if (serverURLS != null){
             serverURL = new URL(serverURLS);
         }

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)serverURL.openConnection();

        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() { 
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        } 
        });

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

        wr.write(message);

        wr.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
```

Here ServerURL is initialized as

```
private URL serverURL = null;
```

When I try to execute this method I get an exception at Line,

> OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

The exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

URLs use forward slashes (/), not backward ones (as windows). Try:

```
serverURLS = "https://abc.my.domain.com:55555/update";
```

The reason why you get the error is that the URL class can't parse the host part of the string and therefore, `host` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

This code seems completely unnecessary:

```
String serverURLS = getRecipientURL(message);

serverURLS = "https:\\\\abc.my.domain.com:55555\\update";

if (serverURLS != null){
    serverURL = new URL(serverURLS);
}
```

1. `serverURLS` is assigned the result of `getRecipientURL(message)`
2. Then immediately you overwrite the value of `serverURLS`, making the previous statement a [dead store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store)
3. Then, because `if (serverURLS != null)` evaluates to `true`, since you **just** assigned the variable a value in the preceding statement, you assign a value to `serverURL`. It is impossible for `if (serverURLS != null)` to evaluate to `false`!
4. You never actually use the variable `serverURLS` beyond the previous line of code.

You could replace all of this with just:

```
serverURL = new URL("https:\\\\abc.my.domain.com:55555\\update");
```

Comment: Hi, That line is added by me just to check the reason for the error. Actually the URL is filtered using the message. Note that the assignment of ServerURLs is a Test line :)

Answer (score 0):

Might help some else - I came here because I missed putting two // after http:. This is what I had:

> http:/abc.my.domain.com:55555/update